# using custom library in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, xamarin

is it possible to use custom library in react-native which was used in Xamarin native project?
ecu firmware is updated through library called autientFx which was written in c# through BLE using Xamarin Native App

so is it possible to use that same library autientFx in react-native app ?
if yes, is there any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: you can use native bridging in react-native , it that way you can use the existing xamarin package in react-native. about the specific library 'autientFx' i never heard about it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @ShoyebMemon, but the library is written in c# but if i want to use this native bridge it means that i have to use native code which is java in android and swift in IOS, is it still possible to use that library that is written c# using native bridging?

Comment: yes it is possible to bridge a c# project , though i have never done it myself. https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows/issues/2034 there are a few details which might help you.

Comment: @ShoyebMemon that's a react native for windows which has its own framework  developed by microsoft and is completely different from react-native that we develop for ios and android? do you think its still applicable for react-native? have you done this way before or any blog or website saying how to doit? sorry for the long reply